# disable HashPassword asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Individual User Accounts for the Authentication with Asp.net mvc5. 
Now, i need to disable HashPassword for the identity, i want to set just the normal password,  because i can not add new user manually to AspNetUsers's table..

.[image: i have added photo for clarification]

Comment: so... to add users manually to the database, you will store the passwords in plaintext?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: can you not utilize the register code? How many people do you need to add manually?

Comment: i want to disable the hashpasword to be normal password

Comment: The reason why the passwords are hashed is because of a reason. If you want to save passwords without any kind of encryption, then please make your own login system. And it's easy to do: you just need a database

Comment: @HugoWoesthuis so can not do it with out doing my own login system ?

Comment: @John Yes. You can't turn off the hash in the built-in login system of ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The reason why the passwords are hashed is because of security reasons. If you want to save passwords without any kind of encryption, then you should make your own login system. And it's easy to do: you just need a database and some C# Knowledge. Here on Stack Overflow (and other networks) are thousands of examples how to create a simple login system. I can even give mine if you want.

Comment: i will try to create my own login system thanks for your help